# Missing divisors in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

Inside the complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$, a linear equation defines a complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$. But a quadratic equation also defines a $\mathbb{CP}^1$ $\big($recalling that $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is topologically a sphere, this is clear from the degree genus relation $g = \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$$\big)$.

However, if we want to use algebraic geometry to describe objects on the two hypersurfaces, the two situations are not equivalent. In the first case, taking the intersection with a second linear equation gives a point, but in the second case this gives two points. More generally, we cannot pick out an odd number of points on the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ with polynomials on the ambient space. Hence, from the perspective of the ambient space we are 'missing' half the divisors on the hypersurface.

Clearly this is a simple example of a more general phenomenon, in which the lattice of divisors of a complete intersection does not descend from that of the ambient space, despite the lattice ranks being equal. My question is whether there is still in these cases some way to make use of the tools of algebraic geometry to describe the 'missing' divisors.

A different but perhaps motivating situation is when the effective divisors on a complete intersection do not descend from those of the ambient space, but it is still possible to describe them, by using ineffective divisors on the ambient space which become effective when restricted to the complete intersection.

Comment: Of course it descends from the ambient space. You’re talking about the linear systems $|H|$ and $|2H|$, not $|H|$ and $|H|$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure what you mean. One cannot pick out a single point on the quadratic hypersurface by intersecting it with the zero-set of a polynomial, since a linear polynomial already picks out two points. So the hyperplane class of the quadratic hypersurface $\mathbb{CP}^1$ does not descend from an integral multiple of the hyperplane class on the $\mathbb{CP}^2$ ambient space.

Comment: The abstract isomorphism with $\Bbb P^1$ is irrelevant. It is the ambient linear systems that are relevant.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think we are talking at cross purposes, so I must have phrased my question poorly. Let me try to ask it in a different way:

Comment: Imagine that I don't know how to compute line bundle cohomology on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, but I do know how to do it on $\mathbb{CP}^2$. If I represent $\mathbb{CP}^1$ as the zero-set of a linear equation inside $\mathbb{CP}^2$, I can compute any line bundle cohomology on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by using an appropriate exact sequence of sheaves on the $\mathbb{CP}^2$. But if I represent $\mathbb{CP}^1$ as the zero-set of a quadratic equation instead, this seems impossible for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2n+1)$. My question is: if we imagine that I'm forced to use the quadratic representation, what can I do?

Comment: OK, I had missed your point. Indeed, even for a projectively normal subvariety, we indeed not guaranteed that every divisor (line bundle) is cut out by $\mathscr O_{\Bbb P^n}(k)$. If that were so, the Picard variety wouldn't be very interesting :)